# Digital servo for my robot arm?

Tags: motors, robotics, servo

I'm planning on using this servo for my robotic arm project:

[Amazon link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/yusvwkj-Digital-Torque-Waterproof-Control/dp/B08MTB1X84/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?crid=3FW87FTTM5LPT&keywords=35kg+servo&qid=1645197363&sprefix=35kg+servo%2Caps%2C101&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEzTVhNMjIwQ09UM1BWJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNzI2MzM0MktPU0pBOU9PRU1FRCZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwMTQ0MDU2M1JOV0JKM0NRRVFMWCZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=).

It's a digital servo with 35 kg-cm (3.4 Nm) torque. However, when looking at other robotic arm projects, I've mainly seen analog servos being used. Is there a reason for that?

**Will I be able to use this servo for my robot arm project with my Arduino and a suitable motor drive?**

Comment: Cost. Product recommendations are off topic.

Comment: What are the specs for your robot arm? mass ? capacity? etc

Comment: The servo will be for the wrist movement, which needs 2.4Nm of torque from my calculations. My questions is basically, if there is a difference in controlling a digital servo vs a analog servo

Comment: The mass from the wrist to the hand is: 550g (mass of hand) + 500g (mass of payload).

Comment: @DKNguyen, yes the product recommendation is not necessary. My main question here is the one I stated above.

Comment: What do you you understand the difference between digital and analogue servos? It's just a marketing term as far as you need to worry...

Comment: Ah ok i see thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analogue and digital servos work the same way from the user's point of view. Internally, the  demanded position and the measured position are compared, the difference being called the error. The calculation of the error and the subsequent control of the motor can be done with analogue or digital electronics. The latter is meant to offer a more intelligent control of the motor. This may improve the response time and allow the servo to be more sensitive to small errors without overshooting.